# How to wrap text in a textarea in the same way content of inline elements is wrapped?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, browser

Is there a way to wrap text in the `textarea` in the same way other elements of the same size wrap the same content made of plain text and inline elements?
I need this to highlight some parts of a text in the `textarea`.

Depending on the text in the `textarea`, the number of things that I need to highlight (number of `span` elements and their positions), and the size of the container, the below-posted solution works fine in ~99% cases. However, in some cases, and in some browsers (e.g. Chrome, Opera, Edge), it just breaks (check attached image).

[image]

The [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/lzoran/cmwvoeuz/) (*open in the Chrome browser and resize output container till it breaks*).

Comment: It is working as expected. Doesn't break no matter how I resize...

Comment: @Zoran, if you want to highlight text, I would recommend using an editable `div` as input.

Comment: You can also play around a bit with this - https://codersblock.com/blog/highlight-text-inside-a-textarea/

Comment: @decpk could you please check the output for the following widths: 635px, 626px, 601px, 580px, 489px

Comment: @ZoranLuledzija no luck on these screen widths.

Comment: @decpk, Thanks for the effort... I don't know what could be, but on my machine (win10; FHD 15") I have this issue during the resize of the output container :/

Comment: @Endothermic_Dragon I've checked the `highlight-within-textarea`, and the same issue can be easily reproduced in Chrome if I change the font-size and font-family. In general, that is the same idea I want to use...  

Regarding the proposed `contenteditable`, I don't have the reported issue. However, I've encountered other problems there (e.g. jumping cursor to the end, a lot of javascript for handling new lines in different browsers, etc.).